# Using Curl and PUT request to edit JSON file

Tags: json, bash, curl

I'm trying to edit an endpoint on a REST API that gives me an array of objects. I want to edit the json file but I've been having trouble with formatting the HTTP request.

the output of the endpoint is something like

```
"result" : [
  {
     "MAC" : "00:08:00:4A:A1:B3",
     "available" : true,
     "bridge" : "br0",
     "ipv4" : {
        "dns1" : "",
        "dns2" : "",
        "gateway" : "",
        "ip" : "",
        "mask" : "",
        "mode" : ""
     },
     "ipv6" : {
        "delegatedPrefixLength" : 64,
        "dns1" : "",
        "dns2" : "",
        "enabled" : false,
        "fixedIp" : [],
        "gateway" : "",
        "ip" : [],
        "linkLocalIp" : [],
        "mode" : "DELEGATED",
        "prefixDelegationEnabled" : false
     },
     "name" : "eth0",
     "nitype" : "ETHER",
     "type" : "LAN"
  },
  {
     "available" : false,
     "bridge" : "br0",
     "ipv4" : {
        "dns1" : "",
        "dns2" : "",
        "gateway" : "",
        "ip" : "",
        "mask" : "",
        "mode" : ""
     },
     "ipv6" : {
        "delegatedPrefixLength" : 64,
        "dns1" : "",
        "dns2" : "",
        "enabled" : false,
        "fixedIp" : [],
        "gateway" : "",
        "ip" : [],
        "linkLocalIp" : [],
        "mode" : "DELEGATED",
        "prefixDelegationEnabled" : false
     },
     "name" : "eth1",
     "nitype" : "ETHER",
     "type" : "LAN"
  }
```

]

I need to be able to append some fields in the first object in the array. I have tried

```
curl -k -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{[{"ipv4":{"mode":"DHCP"},"name": "eth0", "type":WAN}]"}' https://192.168.2.1/api/ni?token=$token1
```

but I keep getting an error saying that it's expecting a and object/value/array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PUT data does not have a top-level JSON field:

`{[{"ipv4":{"mode":"DHCP"}, ...`

The API is probably expecting something like this:

`{"request": [{"ipv4":{"mode":"DHCP"}, ...`

Check your documentation & examples for that API.